# Rails 4: How to render a method with multiple returns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, partial

A method with multiple returns

```
def savings_for(id)
    payments = Payment.user_of(id).all
    savings = 0
    num = 0
    payments.each do |payment|
    item = Item.find(payment.id)
        num = num+1
        savings += item.price
    end
    return savings, num
end
```

I´m using this helper in a view. Like this

```
<p>You´ve save <b><%=savings_for(current_user)%>$</b></p>
```

But I don´t know how render correctly:

```
You´ve save  [#<BigDecimal:108289ca0,'0.13E3',9(27)>, 3]$
```

Update: Changed the return method:

```
return "<b>#{savings}€</b> en #{num}"
```

How i can render the html bold tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, a helper method that is supposed to return something to render on a page, should return a string, not an array of multiple values.

You should decide yourself how you *want* the multiple values to display. How do you want them to display? Maybe just separated by a comma? Okay, so format it like that yourself inside the helper method:

```
  ...
  return "#{savings}, #{num}"
end
```

**updated answer for updated question**

> Update: Changed the return method:
>
> ```
> return "<b>#{savings}€</b> en #{num}"
> ```
>
> How i can render the html bold tag?

I'd do this:

```
 def render_savings_for(savings, num)
    safe_join(
       content_tag("b", "#{savings}€"),
       " en ",
       num
    )
 end
```

Writing your own html-rendering helpers can look a bit confusing, but there are really just a few simple concepts around html safety to understand. I've previously tried to explain some of them here: https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/you-never-want-to-call-html_safe-in-a-rails-template/

Another alternative would be using a view partial instead of a helper method, which wouldn't require you to pay attention to html_safety tricks it would just take care of it for you, but for something this simple I think a helper method is simpler.

Next, you're going to start asking about i18n... make a new question! :)

Comment: Or add a wrapper if `savings_for` is used elswhere as is.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking something like this;

```
<p>You´ve save <b><%=savings_for(current_user).to_f.round(2)%>$</b></p>
```

if you decide to return savings only like this;

```
...
  return savings
end
```

otherwise if you want both you should do this;

```
 ...
  return "#{savings.to_f.round(2)}, #{num}"
end
```

and in the view;

```
<p>You´ve save <b><%=savings_for(current_user) %>$</b></p>
```